# Remove <word> and </word> from a text using python

Tags: python

I have a problem. I am trying to remove `<script>` and `</script>` from a sentence using python. But I only can remove the word of script only. I can't remove the angle brackets too.

The sentence is: `sentence = "<script> document.write("Hello word");</script>"`

The output that i want: `document.write("Hello word");`

I can't find something like that on a python explanation.

Is this possible and what do I need to use then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `.replace`

```
sentence = sentence.replace("</script>","")
sentence = sentence.replace("<script>","")
#output sentence = " document.write('Hello word');"
```

Also, you should initialize `sentence` in this way:

```
sentence = "<script> document.write('Hello word');</script>"
```

If you use `"` inside the string too, you will get an `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` error